# AWS powershell :Get value of a Tag in ec2 instance

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-powershell

I can fetch the Tag's key-value pair of a instance using powershell.

I have an object, `$instance` and `$instance.Tags` yields the following list:

```
Key                                     Value                                  
---                                     -----                                  
abc                                     cde
mnp                                     mju
```

How can I retrieve the value of any specific key?

Comment: What is the command you are using to get that list?

Comment: I fetched the instance object($instance) and `$instance.Tags` fetched these two list

Answer (score 8):

You can access by filtering on the `key`:

```
$instance.Tags | ? { $_.key -eq "mnp" } | select -expand Value
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I tried it, but it's value didn't yield any data.

Comment: I've done similiar stuff in python , it worked. 
In powershell I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Verified that this works following the edit made.  Based on OP's description, it looks like he is using the Tags property of `Amazon.EC2.Model.Instance`, which is returned by `Get-EC2Instance`.

Answer (score 0):

```
($instance.tags | ? $_.key -eq "mytag").value
```

Comment: Could you please explain how this answer solves the OP's question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21599048)